# Difference in methods: coarse and fine frequency correction algorithm

Tags: digital-communications

I am currently studying frequency and phase correction methods. Most probably my question very basic but i am having difficulties to understand it.

Could you please explain what is a difference between coarse and fine correction **algorithms** ( method to correct them)?

I read the post ["Difference between Fine and Coarse Frequency Offset in OFDM"](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/43235/difference-between-fine-and-coarse-frequency-offset-in-ofdm).

This post gives an explanation what are fine and course correction, but it doesnt explain a difference in methods to correct

Comment: I think you're mixing up problem description and algorithm. The way you correct a frequency offset is by multiplying with a sinusoid (you should probably know that if you read stuff about OFDM!), or by an integer shift in discrete frequency domain (but that of course only allows for discrete corrections). There's really not anything more to that – not quite sure what you mean with "algorithm".

Comment: Oh, I just saw your previous post starts with "I'm new to DSP". OK, sorry, you might be trying to understand things from the hard end instead of starting with a didactically sensible start from the basics. Asking about difference between things where you don't understand the problem they solve will not take you anywhere. Get a textbook, start at page 1. Don't try to skip the basics, you're not going to save any time doing that.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a signal $x(t)$ that has a frequency offset estimate of $\hat{f}$ and phase offset estimate of $\hat{\theta}$, then the corrected signal is given as:

$$ x_c(t)=x(t)e^{j(2\pi \hat{f}t+\hat{\theta})} $$

This is the correction part. The estimation part, whether it is coarse fine or both, is how to determine what $\hat{f}$ and $\hat{\theta}$ values are.